# Error while loading the default page on Facebook App

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

Hello everyone,
             i am new to codeigniter and Facebook App.  I went through one tutorial for the Facebook App with codeigniter.  I did all the settings and everything but when i load the application, it throws me this error "An Error Was Encountered.
 The action you have requested is not allowed.".
I am using the default welcome.php page  which have the echo statement.

```
 class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

   function index(){
    echo 'checking';
   }
}
```

Thanks for helping in advance..

Comment: We cannot fix what we cannot see! Post the code where you think the problem lies.

Comment: posted the code.. this is simple echo statement in the welcome controllet to check if its working or not.

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with your code. May be there is a problem in your configuration.

Comment: There is not much in the config file.  Its default for now.  Do you think there can be any problem with Facebook App settings?

Comment: There may be several problems. You might have the API key wrong or missed something in the tutorial or using deprecated API. The error you posted is vague and doesn't help in any way to identify the problem. Post what tutorial you followed, what changes to made and more detaiks like that.

Comment: i am following this tutorial:  http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/

Comment: as per the code which i have posted i can should see that on facebook app right?

Answer (score 1):

i figured out the problem.  The problem was with the Cross Site Request Forgery settings in config file.  when $config['csrf_protection'] was enabled, i was not able to access the app.  But when  i setted the $config['csrf_protection']=FALSE.  it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that can be your problems, your FB app configuration and your permission setting either in htaccess or file permission